# Rails 4 Hstore, array escaped quotes

Tags: ruby, postgresql, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I'm trying to store a Hash of arrays using Rails 4 and Hstore (Postgres 9.2) for when users submit a form with a bunch of checkboxes.  The problem I'm having is that once they're stored, all the values get quotes escaped and it's unreadable when retrieved

```
irb(main):070:0> Plan
=> Plan(id: integer, email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, professional: boolean, preferences: hstore)
irb(main):070:0> params = {"plan"=>{"first_name"=>"nick", "email"=>"test@test.com", "professional"=                                                                                  z", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}}
=> {"plan"=>{"first_name"=>"nick", "email"=>"test@test.com", "professional"=>"true"}, "preferences"=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}}
irb(main):071:0> plan = Plan.new(params['plan'])                                              => #<Plan id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: "nick", professional: true, preferences: nil>
irb(main):072:0> plan.preferences = params['preferences']
=> {"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}
irb(main):073:0> plan
=> #<Plan id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: "nick", professional: true, preferences: {"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}>
irb(main):074:0> plan.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "plans" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "preferences", "professional", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 18 Nov 2013 15:44:46 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@test.com"], ["first_name", "nick"], ["preferences", {"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}], ["professional", true], ["updated_at", Mon, 18 Nov 2013 15:44:46 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):075:0> plan
=> #<Plan id: 27, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2013-11-18 15:44:46", updated_at: "2013-11-18 15:44:46", first_name: "nick", professional: true, preferences: {"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}>
irb(main):076:0> plan_out = Plan.find(27)
  Plan Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 27]]
=> #<Plan id: 27, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2013-11-18 15:44:46", updated_at: "2013-11-18 15:44:46", first_name: "nick", professional: true, preferences: {"foo"=>"[\"\", \"bar\", \"baz\", \"bak\"]", "goo"=>"[\"\", \"gar\", \"gaz\", \"gak\"]", "too"=>"[\"tar\", \"taz\", \"tak\"]", "preferences"=>"{\"foo\"=>[\"\", \"bar\", \"baz\", \"bak\"], \"goo\"=>[\"\", \"gar\", \"gaz\", \"gak\"], \"too\"=>[\"tar\", \"taz\", \"tak\"]}"}>
irb(main):077:0> plan.preferences
=> {"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"], :preferences=>{"foo"=>["", "bar", "baz", "bak"], "goo"=>["", "gar", "gaz", "gak"], "too"=>["tar", "taz", "tak"]}}
irb(main):083:0> plan_out.preferences
=> {"foo"=>"[\"\", \"bar\", \"baz\", \"bak\"]", "goo"=>"[\"\", \"gar\", \"gaz\", \"gak\"]", "too"=>"[\"tar\", \"taz\", \"tak\"]", "preferences"=>"{\"foo\"=>[\"\", \"bar\", \"baz\", \"bak\"], \"goo\"=>[\"\", \"gar\", \"gaz\", \"gak\"], \"too\"=>[\"tar\", \"taz\", \"tak\"]}"}
irb(main):085:0> plan_out.preferences['foo']
=> "[\"\", \"bar\", \"baz\", \"bak\"]"
irb(main):086:0> plan_out.preferences['foo'].first
=> "["
```

So you can see that the plan is fine in it's instance, but when retrieved from the db, the hstore it's escaped and comes out as a string.  My Plan model looks like this:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  store_accessor :preferences, :foo, :goo, :too

  validates :email, presence:true, email_format:true
  validates :professional, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false], :message => "? - Please choose 'Yes' or 'No' for Nutrition Professional"}
end
```

Any insight would help.  Am I trying to do something that Hstore can't do?  I'd hate to have to do the full relational db for these records, it seems like a good use for serializing.

Thanks!

Comment: what version are you using? `4.0.0` or `4.0.1` this look like bug.but this was corrected in version `4.0.1` in > `4.0.0` hstore serilized by default.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using 4.0.1, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: With a similar situation to what I described above?  Using arrays in the has values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, HSTORE values are just plain strings.

This is what the documentation says: ["Keys and values are simply text strings."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html)

So you might convert the values yourself.

Another possibility would be to use the super nice JSON features of Postgres. Those should allow native array storing.

Comment: I had read that also, but I was thinking that Rails was able to decode the array when it retrieved the record.  I guess not.  I've confirmed that it works perfect when the values of the hash are just single strings or integers.